# How to edit User Role Permissions in Database in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin

Is there an alternate way to change the resources available to each user role? The "System" resource has been removed from the admin role, so alas, I can't access the role resource UI in order to restore these permissions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the table `authorization_rule` and permissions are in the column `resource_id`

Find the `role_id` you want to modify in the table `authorization_role` and do

```
UPDATE `m2_authorization_rule` SET `resource_id`='Magento_Backend::all', `permission` = 'allow' WHERE role_id = 'ROLE_ID_TO_MODIFY';
```